# Calculating how long sales reps are idle

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I wrote a procedure to calculate the number of months elapsed since a sales agent' last sale. It works but runs in over 10 minutes... for 20 rows.

```
Sub Latency()
' this sub-routine is used to calculate the no of recent idle months by an agent
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each rng In Range("BL1:BL13000")
j = 1
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -23 - j) > 0    ' this reads the sales flag             
j = j + 1
If j > 12 Then Exit Do
Loop
ActiveCell.Value = (j - 1)   ' inserts the value to the cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: `BL1:BL13000` seems to be a tad more than 20 rows. Could that be the problem?

Comment: my data looks something like this     Jan | Feb | March........|Dec    with 1's and 0's as flags which indicate sale and No sale. there are around 13000 agents and that's why I am looping 13000 times.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's give this some proper indentation so we can see what's going on.

```
Sub Latency()
    ' this sub-routine is used to calculate the no of recent idle months by an agent
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In Range("BL1:BL13000")
        j = 1
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -23 - j) > 0    ' this reads the sales flag             
            j = j + 1
            If j > 12 Then Exit Do
        Loop
        ActiveCell.Value = (j - 1)   ' inserts the value to the cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Do you see it now? Freeman was absolutely right. You're not looping over 20 rows. You're looping over ***13000***. Why such a large range? Ohhh I know. You want to make sure you're getting all of the data, right? Okay, but *what if* the data range extends past row 13k? You don't just have a performance problem, you also have a correctness problem. [Find the last row instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/3198973)

Let's see what else we've got while we're here though.

> ```
> Sub Latency()
> ```

The default scope for VBA procedures is `Public`. So, you should ask yourself if this is the right thing here. I don't have enough context to say, but you should really be explicit whenever possible anyway. Don't rely on another developer's knowledge. Ever. Be explicit.

> ```
> ' this sub-routine is used to calculate the no of recent idle months by an agent
> ```

Cool! I like seeing short comments like this explaining what the purpose of the procedure is. It's a good comment. The problem is though, I can't figure out how the Sub's name (`Latency`) has anything to do with this. Try to come up with a better name for it.

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> ```

Cool! Good idea! Make it look magical when you turn the screen updating back on! But wait.... you never turn it back on. That's bad. Real bad. If you're going to use this, you need to not only turn it back on at the end of the procedure, but you'll also need to make sure it always gets turned back on with an error handler.

> ```
> For Each rng In Range("BL1:BL13000")
> ```

We talked about this already. Find the last row instead.

> ```
> j = 1
> ```

Why are we starting with `j`? If you're going to use a generic counter variable, start at `i` and work your way up through `j` and `k`. It's just an expected convention.

What I'm actually worried about here is that you've not declared the variable. That means two things.

1. You've not declared `Option Explicit`.
2. This is implicitly a `Variant` type.

I cannot impress this on you enough. ***Use Option Explicit.*** It turns run time bugs into compile time bugs by forcing you to define all of your variables up front.

Why is `Variant` bad? It's bad because a variant can be *anything*. Yes. Anything. I could do this and VBA wouldn't blink twice.

```
j = 1
j = ActiveSheet
```

Seriously, yes. You can do this if you're using variant types. So don't.

> ```
> Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -23 - j) > 0    ' this reads the sales flag             
>     j = j + 1
>     If j > 12 Then Exit Do
> Loop
> ```

- What are all these numbers??? I have no idea what this means at all. Use some well named constants instead.
- Great comment again! However, instead of using a comment, create a function that returns a boolean value.
- [Avoid Activate and Select.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 5):

First things first: before you can improve code, you need to be able to *read* it - and this code is hardly readable.

Let's start with proper indentation and a bit of vertical whitespace:

```
Sub Latency()
' this sub-routine is used to calculate the no of recent idle months by an agent

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng In Range("BL1:BL13000")

        j = 1
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -23 - j) > 0    ' this reads the sales flag             
            j = j + 1
            If j > 12 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        ActiveCell.Value = (j - 1)   ' inserts the value to the cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next rng

End Sub
```

Much better, isn't it? Notice how easier it is to tell the nested loops now?

You're switching off `ScreenUpdating` and that's very good... but you're not turning it back on... and that's very bad!

Now, you're looping from row 1 all the way down to row ...13000, an arguably random number that might just as well be 2345678. You say you have 20 rows to loop over, but you're making 13 thousand iterations! Certainly *some* of these iterations are happening over empty rows?

You should be [finding the last row you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1188513), and only loop through the relevant rows you actually need to loop into.

That should help performance a bit.

---

The single most expensive thing you can do in VBA, is probably accessing a worksheet and writing to it. Doing it 13000 times is sure to hit hard.

If you can, compute the values into an array, and dump them all at once onto the spreadsheet, making 13000 cell writes in a single operation (well, assuming the 13000 1's written to the `ActiveCell` *are* a requirement, that is).

This brings me to my last point: avoid `Select` (and `Activate`) and `ActiveCell` at all costs - use explicit cell references instead; `Select`, `ActiveCell`, `Selection` and `Activate` are macro-generator-grade code, that's error-prone and ...well, ugly and hard to follow.